# Why Options trading is charged on per contract basis

Tags: united-states, options, fees, online-trading, contracts

I have been trading options for years, but could not understand why Brokerages charge fee on basis of number of contracts.

Per Fidelity : Trade for just $4.95 per online trade, plus $0.65 per contract.
Per Etrade : $6.95(or 4.95) plus 0.75/0.50

Is the cost for brokerage different if some one sells/buy 10 contracts or 1 contract ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things in life where the commission cost increases despite only a nominal additional overhead cost as the size of the transaction increases.  Brokerage is one of them.

Brokers either charge a flat fee per trade with a bump of '$X" per contract (multiple contracts) or they simple charge a fee per contract.  Why?  Because they can.

Answer (score 2):

The *marginal* cost of processing a trade of one more contract is absolutely negligible. But so is the *marginal* cost of processing one more trade!

Yet somehow the cost of developing and operating the entire trading infrastructure (which is much larger than the *marginal* costs times the volume of trade) needs to be borne by its users. Some principle for sharing this burden has to be arrived at -- and immediately it would seem *at least* as fair to do it in proportion to the number of contracts, as to the number of trades.

Answer (score 0):

Due to listing rules, US exchange listed options may only be traded on an options exchange registered with the SEC.

All of the exchanges currently charge a fee per contract.  Some (maker-taker exchanges) offer a rebate for posting in the book, which depending on your broker, may be passed on to the end-customer.

If they did not do this, but instead charged a fixed amount per trade, a customer could put in a marketable order for 10,000 contracts which would have to be executed on whatever exchange is at the NBBO at the time.  If that was only an expensive maker-taker exchange charging $0.90 per contract, the broker would have to pay $9,000 for the trade.

While exchanges may not in fact charge this much (their fees can change monthly) and a customer may not be able to open a position of 10,000 contracts (due to maximum position limit rules, or adequate liquidity) you get the idea that if the broker could offer trading of options on a per-trade basis, they could lose money.   As a result, they have to charge per-contract.  Some brokers offer cost-plus pricing, where you pay a fixed amount plus or minus whatever the exchange costs or rebates.